# Using a third party library for collection of web events, push data to local servers

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

Most 3rd party analytics services that rely on client-side tracking (i.e. Javascript tags) are built around the assumption that you want to push data to the third party's servers, and then use their reporting front-end.

For a company with a large data warehouse, there is often a requirement to join the web (or mobile) events data to offline data on a persistent unique user id. From there, the company will have it's data scientist/devs/analysts build custom reports and front end dashboards.

I'm looking for a solution that handles all client-side tracking, but assumes you want to push the data to a local data warehouse.  The solution must allow for a persistent unique user id to be associated with each event (unlike Google Analytics). I am NOT concerned with a reporting front end.

EDIT: the real limitation seems to be exporting data at per-event, per-user granularity *from an API call, intra-day.* Mixpanel allows this level of granularity, but only every 24 hours as a data dump.

Answer (score 1):

**edit** based on clarification in comments

> A couple clarifications: 1. I'm looking to push web event data to my
>   own servers, not push offline data to Google's Servers. 2. Google does
>   not allow for export of data at per user id granularity. 3. Mixpanel
>   does allow for export at per user id granularity, but only every 24
>   hours as a giant data dump

Here are the 2 that I have seen come up most often in my web analytics adventures:

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is an open source tracking solution that you install and collect data on your own server. The main advantage to this one is that it's free. But it is also really popular and has a robust community.

Alternatively, [WebTrends](http://webtrends.com), has a version that can be installed on your own server (Analytics on Premises). Personally I'm not a fan of WebTrends, but I've had some clients swear by it for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: A couple clarifications: 1. I'm looking to push web event data to my own servers, not push offline data to Google's Servers. 2. Google does not allow for export of data at per user id granularity. 3. Mixpanel does allow for export at per user id granularity, but only every 24 hours as a giant data dump.

Comment: @BenRollert aah sorry I misunderstood the question. I have edited my answer